# How to convert multidimensional int array to multidimensional string array

Tags: c#

I have tried the stringbuilder but it will merge teh columns

```
// I have this array

{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };

//I want to convert it to a string 

1 2
3 4
5 6

 // with string builder 


        var output = new string[a.GetUpperBound(0) + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j <= a.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                sb.Append(a[i, j]);

            output[i] = sb.ToString();
        }

            the results will be 
                12
                34
                56
```

I found many methods to convert single array but I couldn't find a one for multidimension array

Comment: create a stringbuilder, loop over the outer dimension { loop over the inner dimension { write values}, write newline }, call tostring on the builder?

Comment: I already did but it will not give me what I need, it merge the columns

Comment: you need to add the whitespace yourself; typically by just `if(col != 0) sb.Append(' ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple solution, switch from 2D array to jagged one:

```
  int[][] array = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2, },
    new int[] { 3, 4, },
    new int[] { 5, 6, },
  };
```

Having done so, you can just put as easy as this

```
  string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    array.Select(items => String.Join(" ", items)));

  // 1 2
  // 3 4
  // 5 6
  Console.Write(result);
```

In case of *2D array* you have to implement something like this:

```
  int[,] array = new int[,] {
    { 1, 2, },
    { 3, 4, },
    { 5, 6, },
  };

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); ++i) {
    if (i > 0)
      sb.AppendLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); ++j) { 
      if (j > 0)  
        sb.Append(" ");

      sb.Append(array[i, j]);
    }

  }

  String result = sb.ToString();

  // 1 2
  // 3 4
  // 5 6
  Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: I fail to see how changing from 2D to jagged does anything except add complexity here...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: one can put one line only `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    array.Select(items => String.Join(" ", items)));` to represent *jagged* array as string; in case of *2d array* one has to implement a loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[,] array = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            sb.Append(array[x, y] + " ");
        }
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Console.Write(sb);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You will get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.GetLength(0); x += 1)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < arr.GetLength(1); y += 1)
            {
                sb.Append(arr[x, y]).Append(" ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
```